VBA Change Date Format To dd mmmm yyyy
I have date in column L start from row 2 to the last row found, that I wish to change the format to dd mmmm yyyy.
Does anyone know how to code this?
Thank you in advance

Please edit your question to show what you have tried and where you have run into problems. Suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to How to Ask a Good Question, and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Apply Date Format to Populated Column
Sub ApplyDateFormat()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    With ws.Range("L2")
        With .Resize(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"
            ' to force e.g. US format:
            '.NumberFormat = "[$-409]dd mmmm yyyy" ' '17 April 2024'
        End With
    End With
     
End Sub


I've tried it. But it only change my first row. Is it because the initial format? I've tried to change it to number and date but it's not working.

It only works for dates in the column. You can check if it's a date with the IsDate function: Debug.Print IsDate(ws.Range("L3").Value). If it results in True, the cell contains a date. If it's 'convertible', maybe you could try .Value = .Value after applying the number format.

Pls try.
Sub FormatDate()
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet, arrData, i As Long, aTxt
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    With oSht.Range("L2:L" & lastRow)
        arrData = .Value
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            stxt = Split(Replace(arrData(i, 1), "/", "."), ".")
            If UBound(stxt) = 2 Then arrData(i, 1) = DateSerial(stxt(2), stxt(1), stxt(0))
        Next i
        .Value = arrData
        .NumberFormatLocal = "dd mmmm yyyy"
    End With
End Sub




Does the data should be in number/date/text because idk why it only works when the source data is written like this 36866. While the othder that alr in dd mm yy like such: 19/10/2001, 30.04.2001 are not changed. Sorry for this newbie question. Thank you so much

Excel might not interpret it as a date the way you expect. You'll need to convert it. Please try the updated code.
